# Qt - keep reference of widget in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

In reference to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204738/qlayout-additem-prevent-transfer-of-ownership/40205466#40205466), I need some help with keeping references in my application.

First a snippet from my code.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import os, os.path
import sys

class mainWindowHandler():

    equationEditor = []
    _listview = None
    _window = None       

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def showAddEquation(self):
        """Creates a new instance of the dynamic editor for adding an equation"""

        #create a horizontal split layout
        window = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        current = len(self.equationEditor) - 1
        de = QtGui.QPushButton(str(current))
        self.equationEditor.append(de)

        de.clicked.connect(self.clicked)                    

        #fill list view with items from equation collection
        listview = QtGui.QListWidget()
        for equation in self.equationEditor:
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(equation.text())
            listview.addItem(item)            
        layout.addWidget(listview)
        layout.addWidget(de)

        window.setWindowTitle("Equation {}".format(str(current))
        window.setLayout(layout)

        self._window = window
        self._listview = listview
        window.show()

        return window

    def clicked(self):
        """Method for handling the button events in the solver settings\n
        signal = the button hit\n"""        
        return self.showAddEquation()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ewh = mainWindowHandler()
    window = ewh.showAddEquation()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The application will (later) create a window that allows the manipulation of certain settings - in my code example represented by the `QPushButton`. These settings are later written to a txt-file, but until then I save them in form of there widget. I simply add the widget to a collection and recall them from there. That works well on the Python-level.

Now, I have a button that creates a new instance of the window from inside of the window itself. That works too. But only until the third instance. At that point I loose the reference to my `QPushButton` on the Qt-level. I get the

```
wrapped C/C++ object of type `QPushButton` has been deleted
```

error when trying to retrieve the buttons from my collection (`equationEditor`). In Python they are still there, but obviously the corresponding Qt-objects where destroyed because I somewhere mishandled the references.

Can someone point out a better solution or how I can keep the references?
Thanks...

---

**Edit:**
As there seem to be some confusions I will try to explain the functionality a bit more in detail.

The program starts and creates a window "Equation 1" with a `QListView`and a `QPushButton` "1". In the list view all available `QPushButton` are listed (at start only 1 item). In my actual program the `QPushButton` is `QWidget` with some text fields and the `QPushButton`.

If the user clicks "1" then the button "1" should disappear and a new instance of `QPushButton` named "2" should appear at the position of "1". Additionally, the listview should now hold two items "1" and "2" and the window should have the title "Equation 2". If it is a new window or the same as before with new contents is not relevant. Both variants would be okay. The former is the way it is implemented at the moment. Visible should by only one window at a time.

All instances of `QPushButton` should by collected in a small list (called `equationEditor`) to keep them in the memory. In my actual program this is used for saving all changes made in the widgets without writing the changes to a temp file.

Later, if the user selects item "1" in the `QListView` then the current visible `QPushButton` should be replaced by the `QPushButton` "1" (from the collection `equationEditor`) or if he selects the second item the `QPushButton` "2" should be shown.

Why? 
The widget that will be used later contains a lot of editable data. As the user could edit that at any time it is easier to keep the widgets in memory without showing them instead of repopulating all the data again. As soon as the user selects one in the `QListView` the corresponding widget should be shown in the window so that he can edited the data in the widget again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to understand what exactly you're trying to do. Looking at your code I wonder why it is even working twice before failing.

Btw. I just saw, that there is a [quite accurate description of why it's failing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210374/4124317) in the previous post, given by Schollii

Anyways, I think you should make a new class for the equation window. The main class can then keep track of all opened windows in the `equationEditor` list. It can also add the values of the other opened windows to a new one, once created.

Here is how it would look like

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import os, os.path
import sys

class ShowAddEquation(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Creates a new instance of the dynamic editor for adding an equation"""
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(ShowAddEquation, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        #create a horizontal split layout
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.current = 0 
        self.de = QtGui.QPushButton(str(self.current))
        self.listview = QtGui.QListWidget()

        layout.addWidget(self.listview)
        layout.addWidget(self.de)

        self.setWindowTitle("Equation Editor")
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def setCurrent(self, current):
        self.current=current
        self.de.setText(str(self.current))



class mainWindowHandler():

    equationEditor = []

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def clicked(self): 
        se = ShowAddEquation()
        self.equationEditor.append(se)
        se.de.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        current = len(self.equationEditor) - 1
        se.setCurrent(current)
        for equation in self.equationEditor:
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(str(equation.current))
            se.listview.addItem(item)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ewh = mainWindowHandler()
    ewh.clicked()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks for your code example. I will have a look at it. The tricky part will be the recall of the windows from the memory, when the corresponding item in the listview has been selected.

Comment: As it is now, the number in the listview is exactly the index of the corresponding `ShowAddEquation` instance inside the `equationEditor` list; so there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: That's correct. My itentions are that when an item is selected in the listview the currently shown PushButton is hidden and the PushButton linked to the item is shown in the current window. That is why I actually add the PushButton to `equationEditor` instead of `ShowAddEquation`. In the end the user should see a window where the right sight changes (PushButton) when selecting an item and which is recreated when the user pushs the button.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Should there be one window or many windows? At the beginning you have one window, one listitem and a button. What should happen next? Maybe you can update your question if you want to explain the issue in more detail. Keep in mind that you cannot have the same PushButton in several windows.

Comment: I have tried to explain my problem in more details. Hopefully, it becomes clear now.

Answer (score 0):

So, after understanding the approach given in the first answer I have solved my problem. Here is the working code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Sep  3 14:31:15 2016

"""

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

import os, os.path
import sys

class mainWindowHandler():

    equationEditor = []
    _listview = None
    _window = None       

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def showAddEquation(self):
        """Creates a new instance of the dynamic editor for adding an equation"""

        #create a horizontal split layout
        self._window = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self._listview = QtGui.QListWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self._listview)

        self._listview.clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.changed)        

        self._window.setLayout(layout)       
        #populate the right side of the layout with a button
        self.clicked()        

        self._window.show()

        return self._window

    def clicked(self):
        """Make a new button instance and add it to the window and the collection"""        
        window = self._window
        layout = window.layout()

        current = len(self.equationEditor) - 1
        de = QtGui.QPushButton(str(current))
        self.equationEditor.append(de)

        de.clicked.connect(self.clicked)    
        #close the currently shown button
        item = layout.takeAt(1)
        if item is not None:
            item.widget().close()                
        layout.addWidget(de)

        #fill list view with items from material collection
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setText(de.text())
        self._listview.addItem(item)     
        self._window.setWindowTitle("Equation Editor {}".format(str(current)))        

    def changed(self, index):
        """hide the object on the right side of the layout and show the button at position index in the collection"""
        layout = self._window.layout()
        item = layout.takeAt(1)
        item.widget().close()
        # insert the selected button from the collection
        de = self.equationEditor[index.row()]
        layout.insertWidget(1, de)        
        self._window.setWindowTitle("Equation Editor {}".format(str(index.row() - 1)))        
        de.show()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ewh = mainWindowHandler()
    window = ewh.showAddEquation()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I see what you want now. Although I'm not convinced that this structure can hold, when more real-world information needs to be stored in the Button, if you're happy with it, that's fine.